# Why we cannot declare variable inside if condition but we can inside for

Tags: java, variables

I have this code:

```
int x = 0;
if (boolean k = x > 1) // Syntax error on token "boolean", delete this token

for(int i=0; i < 5; i++) { // This is fine, can still access i inside the body
    //  
}
```

Comment: Because `k` is guaranteed to be `true` inside that `if` body, for example, so what would you want to do with it?

Comment: ["Why" is not a good question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323334/5133585) What kind of answers are you expecting?

Comment: because the developers of the Java Language have specified it that way: [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/index.html) - you must ask them

Comment: If you enter the block depending on `x > 1`, then there is no point in `k` anymore because it will always be `true`. You can just rewrite the lines that depend on `k` with `true`.

Comment: I think it's just because you don't have a code block (`{` and `}`) after your if statement

Comment: @ControlAltDel no, it's just that you can't declare a variable there

Comment: BTW: you can also ask why you can't declare a variable in the condition (second part) or the update (third part) of the for... It is because it generally doesn't make much sense, so why allow it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `if` expects a boolean expression, while a `for` explicitly expects a declaration or assignment expression.

Specifically, syntax of [`if` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9):

```
IfThenStatement:
  if ( Expression ) Statement

IfThenElseStatement:
  if ( Expression ) StatementNoShortIf else Statement

IfThenElseStatementNoShortIf:
  if ( Expression ) StatementNoShortIf else StatementNoShortIf
```

A [basic `for`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1) is defined as:

```
BasicForStatement:
  for ( [ForInit] ; [Expression] ; [ForUpdate] ) Statement

BasicForStatementNoShortIf:
  for ( [ForInit] ; [Expression] ; [ForUpdate] ) StatementNoShortIf

ForInit:
  StatementExpressionList
  LocalVariableDeclaration

ForUpdate:
  StatementExpressionList
  StatementExpressionList:
  StatementExpression {, StatementExpression}
```

(See the links for further expansion of the grammar)

In other words, they have different rules, where the `ForInit` of a `for` allows you to define a variable, while the same doesn't apply to `Expression` used in `if`.

If you're asking *why* it is designed that way, that is basically off-topic as it will pretty much solicit opinions. For example, I think it is designed that way because it usually doesn't make sense to do that in an `if`. As [akuzminykh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12323248/akuzminykh) points out, if the syntax would allow it, in the scope of the `if`, the value will either be `true` (in the `if` block), or `false` (in the `else` block), so being able to declare a variable is wholly unnecessary and pretty much useless, so why allow it. While for a `for` it makes sense to reduce the scope for the iteration variable in that way. On the other hand, [pattern matching for instanceof](https://openjdk.org/jeps/394) does show a case where it is useful to be able to declare a variable in an `if`, it just has a different syntax.

Another reason is that an expression produces a value (the result of the expression), which is then accepted by the `if` for deciding which branch to take. A declaration produces no value, so there would be nothing pass to the `if` for evaluation. Of course, the rules of the language could be changed to accommodate that, but that would mean that variable declaration would be a form of expression, which - without in-depth analysis on my part - would probably result in a nightmare of syntax and unclear scope rules.